# Django handler404 not called on raise Http404()

Tags: python, django, django-templates, http-status-code-404

When i override the handler404 and handler500 in my urls.py like so:

```
from myapp.views import not_found_view

handler404 = not_found_view
handler500 = not_found_view
```

and call `raise Http404()` in my middleware, i see my 404 page.

When i remove both `handler404` and `handler500` from my `urls.py` and `raise Http404()` in my middleware, i see my default 500 error page (from Django Suit) - hence the reason i'm trying to set a custom 404 template to be used on `raise Http404()`'s.

Now my problem: when i remove the handler500 and **only set the handler404**, i also get to see a HTTP 500 page! :|

Why is my `handler500` called when i `raise Http404()` ??

I have multiple template directories in multiple apps, i tried placing a `404.html` in my main app that contains the settings and in another 'normal' app but that didn't work..

I've set `DEBUG` to `False` as well.

Hope someone can answer my question!

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to write your own handlers if you just want to replace Django's template. Django uses `404.html` and `500.html` files for templates and you can replace them with putting file with same name to the directory listed in `settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

In your example that means that you can create `myapp/templates/404.html` and `myapp/templates/500.html` files.

Note that you have to set `DEBUG` to `False` to se those templates.

Check [this article](http://david.feinzeig.com/blog/2012/02/18/tips-for-creating-404-page-not-found-and-500-server-error-templates-in-django-plus-configuring-email-alerts/) for mor details.

Comment: That's exactly what i did, my TEMPLATE_DIRS contains: 'myapp/templates' yet i keep getting a 500 error page

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your ```404.html``` file and you get 500 error because Django crashes. Set up logging to file and check why you are getting 500 error. Check this for help: http://ianalexandr.com/blog/getting-started-with-django-logging-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: Or you can log to console if you are using Django's development server.

Comment: Over the years i've learned that one should always check logs, so i did that before asking the question :) My log says: `raise Http404` as well.. What is strange is that Django doesn't seem to find my `404.html/500.html` in my `templates` dir at all..

Comment: Add this to your urls to check if Django finds template: ```url(r'^404$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.html")),```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either.. I guess i'm stuck returning a HttpResponseNotFound..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75602/discussion-between-domen-blenkus-and-zvl).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation. My custom handler404 **WAS** being called, yet my browser response showed the error500.

Upon inspection, I found I had a syntax error in the template. Thus, the 500 was being caused by that.  I fixed the template and the result was as desired.

The catch 22 is that by default, template debug == debug, so if you set DEBUG=False then the template debug will be false as well; you'll see the 500 error without the template error trace.

So, place a print() statement in your handler404 view, right before returning render() . If you see the output in your django console, you'll know the error is in your template.

You could also try this in your settings.py (django 1.8+) but this didn't seem to work for me, and I didn't follow through once I fixed the template.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {

        'OPTIONS': {
             'debug': True,
         }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The 404-page-not-found-view needs an "exception" argument:

```
def handler404(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'customer/home_page/404.html', status=404)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to replace (monkey-patch) Django's page_not_found.

```
from django.views import defaults
from myapp.views import not_found_view

defaults.page_not_found = not_found_view
```

Monkey-patching is bad practice and may stop working if Django updates internal API, but still may be useful in some situations. Ex. if other methods don't work on some reason.